# Row average in MySQL - how to exclude NULL rows from the count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have simple table (test) where I need to perform some averages (I want to get a row average and a 'total' column average).

```
 id  var1  var2  var3
 1   7     NULL  3
 2   10    NULL  6
```

I notice that MySQL AVG() function excludes NULL values from the count (they're not counted as 0), which is what I want.

In a similar manner, I want this result:

```
var1 var2  var3 total
8.5  NULL  4.5  6.5   (i.e. the overall average is 6.5 *not* 4.3333)
```

But my query looks like this:

```
SELECT
AVG(var1) AS var1,
AVG(var2) AS var2,
AVG(var3) AS var3,
(
 AVG(var1)+ 
 AVG(var2)+
 AVG(var3)
)/3.0 AS metric_total
FROM test
```

which returns a total average of 4.333.

Is it possible in a single query to get a row average that excludes NULL entries from the count in the same way that the AVG() function does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? nice and simple...

```
SELECT
AVG(var1) AS var1,
AVG(var2) AS var2,
AVG(var3) AS var3,
(
 SUM(ifnull(var1,0))+
 SUM(ifnull(var2,0))+
 SUM(ifnull(var3,0))
) / (COUNT(var1)+COUNT(var2)+COUNT(var3))
 AS metric_total
FROM test
```

Comment: Uber hackish, and very efficient. I like it!

Comment: @MMacdonald Please note, with this method, `metric_total` is an overall average of all values in your table. It is not an average of averages. Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4d5a/3

Comment: @vikingsteve thanks for pointing this out. Seems fine if the result is always equivalent. Can you think of any cases where this could go wrong?

Comment: @MMacdonald It is up to you to decide whether this result is suitable for your purpose (follow my link in my previous above comment for an example). This method is blazing fast compared to all other solutions that were suggested here. It just produces a slightly different output (if and only if at least one column contains both `NULL` and non-`NULL` values).

Comment: @vikingsteve Yes, if there are NULL and non-NULL values in any rows, then results are different: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e45d/1. Which could occur for me. Your answer is nonetheless appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    avg1, avg2, avg3,
    ( 
      (COALESCE(avg1, 0) + COALESCE(avg2, 0) + COALESCE(avg3, 0)) -- only add non-null values
      / -- division
      ( IF(avg1 IS NULL, 0, 1) + IF(avg2 IS NULL, 0, 1) + IF(avg3 IS NULL, 0, 1) ) -- number of non-null averages
    ) AS metric_total
FROM
    ( SELECT
        (SELECT AVG(var1) FROM test) AS avg1,
        (SELECT AVG(var2) FROM test) AS avg2,
        (SELECT AVG(var3) FROM test) AS avg3
    ) AS sub
```

The subquery only allows to not repeat the `AVG()` function.

[Have fun!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d113c/14)

Comment: good point about not repeated the average. But my question was how to return a total of 6.5, and your total is still 4.333.

Comment: @MMacdonald This one should do.

Answer (score 1):

You want the average of all of var1, var2 and var3 from all columns. Maybe do a sub select for each column to get its average, with each sub select unioned together. Down side is this will only work if each column has the same number of non null fields

```
SELECT AVG(FirstAvg)
FROM
(
    SELECT AVG(var1) AS FirstAvg
    FROM test
    UNION
    SELECT AVG(var2) AS FirstAvg
    FROM test
    UNION
    SELECT AVG(var3) AS FirstAvg
    FROM test
) Sub1
```

To fix that issue maybe just do the AVG once on the sub selects

```
SELECT AVG(FirstAvg)
FROM
(
    SELECT var1 AS FirstAvg
    FROM test
    UNION
    SELECT var2 AS FirstAvg
    FROM test
    UNION
    SELECT var3 AS FirstAvg
    FROM test
) Sub1
```

To get the averages of the other columns as well:-

```
SELECT AVG(var1), AVG(var2), AVG(var3), AVG(FirstAvg) AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT var1 AS var1, NULL AS var2, NULL AS var3, var1 AS FirstAvg
    FROM test
    UNION
    SELECT NULL AS var1, var2 AS var2, NULL AS var3, var2 AS FirstAvg
    FROM test
    UNION
    SELECT NULL AS var1, NULL AS var2, var3 AS var3, var3 AS FirstAvg
    FROM test
) Sub1
```

Comment: but your total comes out as 5.2 and not 6.5?

Comment: Last one gives me the results you specified you required (ie, 8.5000 NULL 4.5000 6.5000)

Answer (score 0):

instead of `AVG(var1), AVG(var2)` etc try using  `AVG(ISNULL(var1,0)), AVG(ISNULL(var2,0))`

Comment: I don't want to cast NULL to 0. I want to exclude NULL elements from the count in an average calculation.